# Getting Pointer of Managed Type OR Releasing an Event by Handle

Tags: c#, pointers, events

I'm having a program mechanism that I can not really change:

I have a `struct` for contexts.

I use the pointer of the contexts, rather than the `struct` object itself, because **I have to pass this context to unmanaged code, and the unmanaged code will accept only pointer as parameter**, to give it back to me later on callback.

I need to use any restrictive methods to a specific function regarding the contexts so it can be called only once concurrently.

As such, I'd use `SemaphoreSlim`, or if I can't use that, then I still would use `ManualResetEvent` or `AutoResetEvent` as workaround, technically block the function call of the context until the unmanaged code calls the callback, so I can release the lock.

Because I need to pass a pointer to the unmanaged code I convert my context `struct` to `Context*` by *Pinning* it with `GCHandle.Alloc()`, then Getting the pointer by `GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()`.

The problem is in my context `struct` the `SemaphoreSlim`, or `Manual/AutoResetEvent` are a managed type, that makes me unable to get their, or event the context's pointer.

Is there any solution to pin these managed objects and get their pointers, and later cast them back to object?

For example:

```
SemaphoreSlim ss1 = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
SemaphoreSlim* pointerOfSemaphore = &ss1;


SemaphoreSlim ss2 = *pointerOfSemaphore;
ss2.Release();
```

I know because this is not a value type, It is impossible to get it's address by this way, but is there any other solution?

Or, as an alternative solution I can use `Manual/AutoResetEvent` and get their handles as `IntPtr`, but I don't know how to release their `WaitOne()` event (signaling `Set()`) only by having the `Handle`.

Any Ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out this actually works, but I wonder if there is any better solution:

```
    unsafe
    {
        AutoResetEvent myEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        AutoResetEvent coEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        void* eventPtr = (void*)myEvent.Handle;

        Console.WriteLine("Before release");

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
            coEvent.Handle = (IntPtr)eventPtr;

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            coEvent.Set();
        }, null);

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for release");

        myEvent.WaitOne();

        Console.WriteLine("Event released");
    }
```

*(I know I don't have to convert the `IntPtr` to `void*` and then back to `IntPtr`, I did it on purpose, because I pass it that way away to the unmanaged code.)*

By some "undocumented" code and with some help from [here](http://benbowen.blog/post/fun_with_makeref/) I made a workaround with `SemaphoreSlim`, and it actually works.

```
    unsafe
    {
        // Create semaphore
        SemaphoreSlim mySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

        // Get size of semaphore
        SemaphoreSlim[] mySemArr = new SemaphoreSlim[2];
        TypedReference mySemRef1 = __makeref(mySemArr[0]);
        TypedReference mySemRef2 = __makeref(mySemArr[1]);
        int mySemaphoreSize = (int)((UInt64)(*((IntPtr*)&mySemRef2)) - (UInt64)(*((IntPtr*)&mySemRef1)));

        // Get pointer of semaphore
        TypedReference mySemaphoreTypeRef = __makeref(mySemaphore);
        IntPtr mySemaphorePtr = *(IntPtr*)(&mySemaphoreTypeRef);

        Console.WriteLine("Before release");

        // Start new thread
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
            // Convert IntPtr to byte "array"
            byte* sourcePtr = (byte*)mySemaphorePtr;

            // Create dummy semaphore
            SemaphoreSlim castedSemaphore = default(SemaphoreSlim);
            TypedReference castedSemaphoreTypeRef = __makeref(castedSemaphore);
            byte* castedSemaphorePtr = (byte*)*((IntPtr*)&castedSemaphoreTypeRef);

            // Copy mySemaphore to dummy
            for (int i = 0; i < mySemaphoreSize; ++i)
                castedSemaphorePtr[i] = sourcePtr[i];

            // Wait 3 seconds
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            // Release semaphore
            castedSemaphore.Release();
        }, null);


        // Wait for release
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for release");
        mySemaphore.Wait();

        // Released
        Console.WriteLine("Semaphore released");
    }
```

Simplified version:

```
    unsafe
    {
        // Create semaphore
        SemaphoreSlim mySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

        // Get pointer of semaphore
        TypedReference mySemaphoreTypeRef = __makeref(mySemaphore);
        byte* mySemaphorePtr = (byte*)*(IntPtr*)(&mySemaphoreTypeRef);

        Console.WriteLine("Before release");

        // Start new thread
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
            // Create dummy semaphore
            SemaphoreSlim castedSemaphore = default(SemaphoreSlim);
            TypedReference castedSemaphoreTypeRef = __makeref(castedSemaphore);
            byte* castedSemaphorePtr = (byte*)(*((IntPtr*)&castedSemaphoreTypeRef));                    

            // Copy mySemaphore to dummy
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(IntPtr); ++i)
                castedSemaphorePtr[i] = mySemaphorePtr[i];

            // Wait 3 seconds
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            // Release semaphore
            castedSemaphore.Release();

        }, null);


        // Wait for release
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for release");
        mySemaphore.Wait();

        // Released
        Console.WriteLine("Semaphore released");
    }
```

Even though it is working, I'm not happy with this solution. Any better ideas?